# SQL Create User FOR vs. FROM

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any substantive difference between these two SQL statements, as I see them used for the same end goal of creating a database user based off a SQL Login

```
CRETE USER myusername FOR LOGIN myusername

CREATE USER myusername FROM LOGIN myusername
```

Comment: The relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same thing; just different syntax.